# Android 8.0 | How to show the day of the week on my widget (HTC CLOCK) or Notifications area at the top

Tags: stock-android, htc-10

so I have this problem of not knowing the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday,...) and having it on my HTC 10's home screen or the notifications pane would help a lot. I remember that one of the above-mentioned items showed the day of the week along with the date, but I don't know why it is gone. Any help will be much appreciated.

P. S. Priority is to avoid installing third-party apps for this simple thing.